# "Don't let it get you down" or "Don't let it gets you down"

Tags: grammar

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Let_It_Get_You_Down

Why it is "Don't let it get you down" and it is not "Don't let it gets you down"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use 'let', meaning 'permit' or 'allow', with the bare infinitive and 'get' is a bare infinitive.

Don't let the dog eat the meat (not *eats*), I will let you go (not *goes*), she won't let me have a cake (not *has*), don't let it make you sad (not *makes*).

> let verb (ALLOW)   [ T **+ infinitive without to** ]
>
> to allow something to happen, or someone to do something, by not doing
> anything to stop an action, or by giving your permission:
>
> *He decided to let his hair grow long.
>
> Let your shoes dry completely before putting them on.
>
> I'm letting you stay up late, just this once.
>
> Don't let it worry you.*

[Let (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/let)